# company-mode doesn't work on latex environment

Tags: latex, auctex, company-mode

I've installed the company package in order to get an auto-completion functionality. It works well in my ESS environment, but no in latex. In fact, no completions are showed in latex buffers when I activate `M-x company-mode`. What could be the problem?

Here it is my `.emacs` config for latex

```
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)

;;
;;ispell config
;;
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "es_ES") ;; Change dictionaries here!
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(("es_ES" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil nil nil utf-8)))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

(setq TeX-output-view-style
    (quote
     (("^pdf$" "." "evince -f %o")
      ("^html?$" "." "iceweasel %o"))))
```

UPDATE:

Removing auto complete configuration for other environments from the init file and adding the following line solves the problem.

```
;;
;; COMPANY
;;

(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq company-idle-delay 0)
  (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2)

  (global-company-mode t)
  )
```

Comment: Do you have any company completion backend for `LaTeX` installed?. You
will can use either `company-auctex` or `company-math` for the
completions to work. See Here
[company-auctex](https://github.com/alexeyr/company-auctex) or here [company-math](https://github.com/vspinu/company-math).

Comment: Just curious: Why don't you use the completion offered by AUCTeX itself?  Try `C-c C-m` (or `C-c RET`) for macros and `C-c C-e` for environments?  With `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` in your init file, you get completion support for packages you use as well (packages supported by AUCTeX).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you use lsp-mode (https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode), there is recent support for LaTeX via the Digestif LaTeX language server (https://github.com/astoff/digestif).